# iOS8 Facebook Extensions Not Accepting Video

Tags: ios, facebook, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios8-extension

UIActivityViewController will show the Facebook extension in iOS 8 if a video url is provided and Facebook SSO is authenticated, just like in iOS 7. In iOS 8 I click on the Facebook extension and the Facebook popover-like form shows with no video thumbnail (unlike iOS7 where the thumbnail shows). Then I enter some text and press 'Post.' The post shows in my news feed with the entered text and no video (unlike iOS 7 where the post contains the video).

Here's my code:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:validFilePath];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[videoURL] applicationActivities:nil];
```

VideoURL is

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/[app id]/Library/video.mp4
```

Reproducible in iOS 8.0 and 8.0.2 on an iPhone 5s. Video URLs work as intended iOS 7 and 7.1 and for UIImages in iOS 7+. Other extensions, such as Mail, SMS, and third party apps such as Evernote, accept videos with no problem in iOS 8+. It's only Facebook I'm having issues with.

Does this code need to change for iOS8 or is it a known iOS 8 bug?